# Docker and wazuh container deploy to lxc container on proxmox

Tags: docker-compose, lxc, proxmox, wazuh

#docker-compose up
I get a system error from Wazun.indexer(failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed).
how can i do for a good installation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a correct installation of Wazuh in Docker, you must follow the following [instructions](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/docker/index.html).

Keep in mind that if you already did a previous installation, it could surely have been incomplete. I recommend you delete the previous installation, making sure that all the volumes created were deleted.

Let me know if the information helped you.

Greetings,

Nicolas